# hive slow performance with this configuration

Tags: hadoop, hive

When i add this configuration command in hive-site.xml ,hive queries is very slow.
Anyone can explain why happened for me?how can we fix it?

```
<property>
<name>hive.support.concurrency</name>
<value>true</value>
</property>
```

this is my hive-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
<value>root</value>
<description>Username to use against metastore database</description>
</property>
<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
<value></value>
<description>Username to use against metastore database</description>
</property>
<property>
<name>hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode</name>
<value>nonstrict</value>
</property>
property>
<name>hive.enforce.bucketing</name>
<value>true</value>
</property>
```

Comment: can you give us more details about the server? how many nodes, which distribution, etc.

Comment: my cluster has 2 node-1master-slave and 1 slave